# How to restrict magento extension to work on one magento installation only?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, license-key

I am working on magento extensions licensing and trying to figure out how to restrict magento extensions to work on one magento installation only.

How would you do it? I believe ioncube doesn't allow to do anything like that. It can only restrict per domain or IP.

PHP is open source and it seems like anybody can crack this protection. I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Unless your rapidflow etc just make something good and provide decent support. Being able to extend and modify broken ass extensions takes up a fair part of my working day.

Comment: Independent to Magento, this *has* been asked before. Search it up, let us know which of the existing solutions you did and why they didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 100% way to achieve what you need. Even the source encoded with commercial encoders like IonCube (which require corresponding software installed btw, so it will restrict your potential auditory at least to managed hostings) don't guarantee to protect your code from modifications and changing the logic.

The best what you can do IMHO is:
1) Implement some logic based on $_SERVER host - i.e. make it per/domain license with allowing some "obviously" non-live domains (like containing dev. etc) - this is good practice
2) Use code obfuscator and encode some "important" piece of your code (for example model or helper class file). Try googling "php code obfuscator".

This is general direction, in fact this is the place where you everyone better figure out it's own unique path, the weirder the better >:o